# FreeForm and HubSpot - Current Page

Tags: plugin-freeform, freeform

We are looking to place a contact form across all pages and want to integrate HubSpot. I noticed that there was the ability to match up the fields with HubSpot - which is great - my question is how do we pass through the current page's Title and URL the form is shown on?

Is there a way of matching the field that or is it done a different way?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It would be fairly easy to create a hidden field and read the page URL into it.
As for the title, is your form an embed inside the channel entries call? Then it's pretty easy to get the title as well. If not you may have to be a bit creative.

Check the hidden field config, it even tells you how to pull in the current url.

Comment: So would it be the following:
overrideValues: { currentPage: craft.app.request.absoluteUrl }